# Any way to simulate F5 BIG-IP server?

Tags: big-ip, f5

We have a potential client that uses F5 BIG-IP servers for load balancing.  In determining if we could cleanly integrate our product with their Load Balancers, I started looking at the API's provided by F5.  The problem is, I can't run any custom code with their API's without an F5 server.  Does anyone know if there is a software equivalent for testing?

As I'm trying to learn how the F5 product works, creating my own mocks doesn't help.  I want to hit various API functions, and learn what gets returned.

Comment: Maybe you could call F5 and ask for a demo unit?

Comment: Always an option, but was hoping for some sort of software solution I could try out before formally contacting F5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For reference of anyone else trying to do the same thing, F5 is now releasing a virtual edition of BIG-IP Server.

Here is a link to a 90 day trial version: [BIG-IP Trial Version](https://www.f5.com/trial/?utm_source=F5+DevCentral+Base+User+List&utm_campaign=54ab541abf-DevCentral_News_16_Feb2_16_2010&utm_medium=email)

Answer (score 0):

While you are looking at F5 demos, you can read about their Application Security Manager in this series of articles on the DevCentral website.  [Fundamentals of the BIG-IP ASM](https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/fundamentals-of-the-big-ip-application-security-manager-what-is-the-asm)

F5 has the popular Local Traffic Manager (LTM) but they also offer several other modules that you might be interested in (the ASM being one of those).  The article listed above has links to other articles as well where you can download virtual editions of test websites and play around with all the features of the F5 modules.  I hope this helps!